# Conditional update in JAX?

Tags: python, autograd, jax

In autograd/numpy I could do:

```
q[q<0] = 0.0
```

How can I do the same thing in JAX?

I tried `import numpy as onp` and using that to create arrays, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JAX arrays are immutable, so in-place index assignment statements cannot work. Instead, jax provides the [`jax.ops`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.ops.html) submodule, which provides functionality to create updated versions of arrays.

Here is an example of a numpy index assignment and the equivalent JAX index update:

```python
import numpy as np
q = np.arange(-5, 5)
q[q < 0] = 0
print(q)
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4]

import jax.numpy as jnp
q = jnp.arange(-5, 5)
q = q.at[q < 0].set(0)  # NB: this does not modify the original array,
                        # but rather returns a modified copy.
print(q)
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4]
```

Note that in op-by-op mode, the JAX version does create multiple copies of the array. However when used within a JIT compilation, XLA can often fuse such operations and avoid copying of data.

Comment: any idea how to do the same thing for a matrix rather than a single element?

Answer (score 0):

To address [@truth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12485764/truth) comment, `jnp.where` would generalise to many dimensions. Here's an example:

```
from jax import numpy as jnp
x = jnp.arange(4).reshape((2, 2)) - 2
print(x)
# Array([[-2, -1], [0, 1]], dtype=int32)
print(jnp.where(q < 0, 0, q))
# Array([[0, 0], [0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

This is jit compatible too (when `jnp.where` is used with 3 arguments).